# Changing value of a variable according to a condition inside a target in Makefile

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

In a makefile which I have ,I want to assign value to a variable based on a condition.
I have:

```
CMAKE=cmake ../
```

I tried doing:

```
if test condition;
then $(eval CMAKE := $(cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../));\
fi;
```

But this does not work.Is there any other way to do this?

P.S The error which is getting reported is :

```
Syntax error: ";" unexpected
```

When I removed ";" ,it showed another error :

```
Syntax error: "fi" unexpected
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of "back and forth" between the shell and make is not possible.  It's important to understand the relationship between them: make does not implement a shell parser: it just runs the shell for that.  All make gets back from the shell is a single exit code that determines whether the command succeeded or not.

Make runs a recipe by first expanding all the variables and functions in the recipe, then passing the resulting command to the shell to be invoked.

Thus it should be clear why your example doesn't work.

Before we can give you good advice we'd need higher-level information about exactly what you're trying to do and why.  One way to do what you want is to use `$(shell ...)` to compute the conditional, all outside of any rule:

```
ifeq ($(shell test condition && echo true),true)
  CMAKE := cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../
endif
```

However, this looks pretty strange to me.  If you described what you really want to do we can probably give you better help.

*ETA:*

Based on your description below, the best option is target-specific variables:

```
CMAKE_BUILD_FLAG = -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=$(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)

debug:   CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = Debug
release: CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = Release

setup:   CMAKE_BUILD_FLAG =

debug release setup: all

all:
        cmake $(CMAKE_BUILD_FLAG) ../
```

Comment: I have two targets debug and release in the makefile. There is yet another target called setup. Depending on which of these is called I need to compile the code. If setup is called then one of the steps in the compilation is 'cmake ../' whereas if debug is called then it is 'cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../' and similarly for release. So I tried using a variable whose value can be changed according to which of the targets has been called.

Comment: Actually debug and release are the same as setup with just one line being different i.e 'cmake ../' so I wanted to do it like above without copying the whole setup and modifying that one single line.

Comment: OK.  Are you saying you can't figure out how to adjust my suggestions above to your needs?